# Shared Preference in case app updating

Tags: android

I am studying android myself

I have one question. Assume, app on playstore is 1.0 version and has not code like following

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("isFirst" , Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        ...
        editor.commit();
```

Now, i developed version 2.0 and i added that code. And, users will update app to version 2.0

Q1. Although app has not that code, shared preference is automatically generated?
Q2. If shared preference isn't generated in version 1, it will be generated when users update app to version 2.0?
Q3. If shared preference is generated in version 1, how i know that user updated app to version 2.0 using code?

My problematic code

```
public boolean CheckAppFirstExecute(){
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("isFirst" , Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean isFirst = pref.getBoolean("isFirst", false);
    if(!isFirst) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("isFirst", true);
        editor.commit();

        ....


    }else{
        Log.d("this is not first", "not first");
    }

    return !isFirst;

}
```

Comment: `Although app has not that code, shared preference is automatically generated?` No.

Comment: `If shared preference isn't generated in version 1, it will be generated when users update app to version 2.0`. Not automatically. Only when you execute that code.

Comment: `If shared preference is generated in version 1....` ??? You said it had not that code. So how should it generate something? I think you have to express yourself better.

Comment: My app(version 1.0) on play store has not code about shared preference. And I want to make app showing up dialog message only when app is installed first time. So, I used `shared preference` to know that user install app first time.
But, I'm not sure that updating app execute this code

Comment: Sorry, i edited

Comment: What is probematic with your code?

Comment: My code is executed well when i test.                      People who has app(version1) will update to version2. In this case, i want to know that `CheckAppFirstExecute()` will be execute.( `CheckAppFirstExecute()` is only included version 2 )

Comment: Your question does not make sense. If you call that function the code will be executed.

Comment: Okay, i have to find way of test. Thank your answer. It is helpful to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q1. Although app has not that code, shared preference is automatically
>   generated?
>
> Q2. If shared preference isn't generated in version 1, it will be
>   generated when users update app to version 2.0?

"getSharedPreferences" is not generating `SharedPreferences` for an application.
It's just returning an interface, by which you can save some types of data in storage.

> Q3. If shared preference is generated in version 1, how i know that
>   user updated app to version 2.0 using code?

If you want to update app on `PlayStore`, it's essential to increase integer value of `versionCode` property inside `build.gradle(Module:app)` file. You can get this value in `Java` by following command: `BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE`.

Comment: `"getSharedPreferences" is not generating SharedPreferences for an application.` I think OP means if the shared preferences file is generated by that code. If data is saved in shared preferences. What else?

Comment: Thank your answer!

Comment: Thank you too. If you find it helpful, please accept it :)